# If extension XPathSelectElements is called get error 'Could not load file or assembly'

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-standard-1.4

I want to use the Extension `XPathSelectElements` in a `netstandard 1.4` project.

The documentation states, that the assembly `System.Xml.Linq` is used.
In my case is `System.Xml.Linq` part of `System.Xml.XPath.XDocument`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356942(v=vs.110).aspx

**Code**

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(content);
var events = xml.XPathSelectElements("/methodCall");
```

**Package Reference**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XPath.XDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Exception**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
"System.Xml.XPath.XDocument, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or one of its dependencies.
```

**Update 1**

A downgrade of the nuget package to 4.0.1 didn't help

[image]

Comment: You're referencing 4.3.0 in your package references. The exception is referring to 4.0.1.0. Is it possible that one of your other dependencies is using 4.0.1.0? I'd make sure they're all consistent to avoid mismatches like this

Comment: I don't understand this version mismatch. But I tried to change it to 4.0.1.

Comment: Are you using any other projects as dependencies? Or is it a self contained project?

Comment: It is a mixture of net core, net standard and full framework projects.

Comment: Can you post more info from the project settings page, interested to see what the build configuration is